# How can I found out why I lost 60 rep on a deleted answer?

Tags: support

I had written an answer to a question called "Why doesn't C# support string enumerations?" That was an actual answer IMO. Today I see in my account that I have recieved -60 rep for that answer and it also deleted.

I cannot even find the question anymore, a search for the question in quotation mark gives me no result, without quotation mark 720, and I cannot see the one. Searching for +why +C# +support +string +enumerations yields 7 hits but not the question I am searching for.

My question is: 
Did the deletion take those 60 reps from me, or was it the consequence of so many people downvoting my answer? (I assume the latter.)
How can I find the question and the answer and the reason why my answer was downvoted and deleted?

Comment: Don't worry, when you reach 10k rep on SO, you [will be able](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) to see [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125891/why-doesnt-c-sharp-support-string-enumerations) again :)

Comment: I had the same issue, for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637952/should-entry-level-programmers-be-able-to-answer-fizzbuzz. It was a good question, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer wasn't down-voted.

What happened would be:

- User asks question.
- You answer it.
- Your answer receives 6 upvotes => +60 reputation.
- For whatever reason the question (and your answer is deleted)
- Your reputation now goes down by 60 points because those votes don't exist any more.

Previously you wouldn't have noticed this and your reputation would have been inflated by these no longer existant votes.

[Recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) now mean that reputation reductions due to deletions are reflected as they happen rather than waiting for a recalculation.

Comment: Thanks to Oded and ChrisF. Chose this answer because it is slightly more explicit. I suppose I have no chance to see, why the question was deleted?

Comment: @KitFisto - It was closed as "not constructive" and then deleted by regular voters.

Comment: Thanks ChrisF. I understand. I don not think that it is fair to remove the earned reputation from the answers though.

Comment: @KitFisto - the reputation was always removed - it just wasn't visible. If you went to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation you'd have seen that the value at the bottom was different to your reported figure and pressing the "Recalculate now" button would have brought the two figures back into line.

Answer (score 4):

The answer got deleted, so any reputation associated with it was also deleted and removed.

This was always happening, but not as visible as the reputation on the site would not normally display this reduction in reputation immediately, but only after reputation recalculations.

This changed [recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes).