# Facilitate finding a user's deleted content

Tags: feature-request, reputation, profile-page, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Lots of people have lost a bit of rep recently due to the *Great Rep Recalc of 2012* (as fortold by the Mayans). Personally I lost around 200, no big deal.

What I would love to see is a way of grouping or exposing the deleted questions in the user's reputation page. I have over 900 answers, and going back through history to find the deleted questions is like looking for the proverbial needle in the haystack.

So why would I want to do this? There are several reasons:

- curiousity. Yes I have answered questions in the past that don't meet the standards for SO, but I still want to know when they've bitten the dust.
- finding answers that were deleted *but the question wasn't*. I found one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1795900/109702) (10K only), which was likely flagged and deleted as *Not an answer*. I've since edited it and flagged for mod attention to get it undeleted (although it may still not meet the standards, that blog post is so short it is impossible to excerpt it without quoting the whole post).

### tl;dr:

Being able to isolate out and examine my deleted answers gives me the opportunity to improve the ones that can be improved. It also makes it easier to show people [exactly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124232/how-can-i-found-out-why-i-lost-60-rep-on-a-deleted-answer) [where](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124293/why-did-my-reputation-drop-10-points) [they lost rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124325/146015). Currently there does not appear to be a [search option](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for this.

**Edit:**

Note that the intent of this question is different to the question *[Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)*. I can already *see* my deleted stuff, I simply want a way to *find* the deleted stuff.

Comment: recalc foretold by the Mayans, rep taken off by the Martians